# Mobile phone, Redirect adding %20 to parameter

Tags: c#, url, string, redirect, mobile

I have a mobile app with a few folders. These folders are used as variables that I will add to parameters:

```
        //Get the URL
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        //Location
        string location = "";

        //Check if string contains /
        if (url.Contains('/'))
        {
            //Get location
            string[] words = url.Split('/');

            //Set location 
            location = words[1];

            //Now check if string contains ?
            if (location.Contains('?'))
            {
                //Remove ?
                string[] removeQ = location.Split('?');

                //Reset location
                location = removeQ[0];
            }

        }
```

After I the path from the URL I have to redirect depending on the phone type:

```
        if (Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("BLACKBERRY"))
        {
            //Now we check the version
            if (double.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) <= 5)
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
            }
            else if (double.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) >= 6)
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
            }

        }
        else if (Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("HTC")) //HTC phones cannot handle JQuery mobile
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
        }
        else if (Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("ANDROID")) //Certain androids are out of date
        {
            if (double.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) > 2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it `location` will have an "%20" added to the front. This will not happen if I test it on a desktop, only on phones.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the spaces from the end of your string literals e.g. change:

```
"http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location= " + location
```

to

```
"http://myWebsite.com/Default.aspx?location=" + location
```

Comment: Ahh. Stupid mistake. Good catch though!

Answer (score 0):

In a URL, spaces are encoded to %20.  You just need to remove any trailing or leading spaces from your strings to amend this.